# Dashboard/Data Display Options for Bluemix Application

Tags: sql, database, dashboard, ibm-cloud, node-red

As part of an IoT project that uses NodeRed in Bluemix, I now need to somehow present this data. I'm at a loss on the best options for me. I can save the data to a sql database, but from there I am looking for a soluton to display these entries I'm pushing from NodeRed to the DB.

Comment: What have you tried?  Stack Overflow is a programming community.  We are glad to help but please show some of the things you have tried or some of your thoughts on how to solve this.

Comment: Some of the things I've looked at is using a Dashboard called "Freeboard" that is supposed to work well with Nodered, however does not save properly within bluemix. After that I thought about pushing the data to a database and updating a static webpage that checks for updates periodically. Currently I am looking at using NodeRed's http output nodes to construct a simple dash that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the simplest way to do this with NodeRed is to use the Template Node and the HTTP Output node.  You can use the Template Node to inject data into a webpage and then serve that webpage in NodeRed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is to use websockets for Nodered to push updates to a webpage I designed as a dashboard.